# How to add templates to rails-latex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, latex, pdflatex

I have recently started working with [rails-latex](https://github.com/jacott/rails-latex) on my Rails application. I would like to use a template when generating a pdf, but don't see any way to do so mentioned in the Github readme. Is there some sort of directory or method to adding LaTeX templates?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the **LatexToPdf.generate_pdf** method.

It takes in two arguments:

- latex content
- a configuration hash

...and returns the pdf binary, which you'll need to write to a file.

Regarding the tex content, I have a directory with latex templates and would read in them using the File class, then pass in the content as an argument.

I suggest reading through the [source](https://github.com/amagical-net/rails-latex/blob/master/lib/rails-latex/latex_to_pdf.rb) to if you need to add configuration.

Note that under the hood, the rails-latex (LatexToPdf) gem still depends on a TeX extension (which you'll need to download) to generate the pdf. The default is pdflatex, and I've personally used xelatex.